# Artisan migrate docker error

Tags: docker, laravel-5, laradock

I have Laradock setup and serving a website in larval, but when I try to run php artisan migrate I get this error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from  information_schema.tables where table_schema = yt and table_name = migrations)



DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yt
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I can not seem to find a solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should check which container run the mysql service :

```
sudo docker ps
```

Maybe it not expose the port from  mysql container to localhost (127.0.0.1) so laravel can't connect to it .
Find the mysql container name then change the DB_HOST .Let take an example:

`app-container   172.0.0.1
 mysql-container  172.0.0.2`

Because when docker run up ,it will create a virtual networking for itself ,then it will expose to your computer .So if you want laravel can work with msql ,you should change the DB_HOST to 172.0.0.2 in this example case  .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Laradock on MacOS, couldn't connect to MariaDB container.

My way:

1. Get correct name for MariaDB container:

`docker ps`

2. Inspect container (for example container name is: *container_mariadb_1*)

`docker inspect container_mariadb_1`

3. At very bottom of long list of parameters you can see IPAddress

`"IPAddress": "172.26.0.3"`

I put this IP in Laravel's .env config file as *DB_HOST* and this is it.
Of course I'm not sure if this way is really correct, but I know that it's work for me at least twice.

**UPDATE:** Also in my case Laravel connects to MariaDB normally if I use `DB_HOST=mariadb` in .env file.